# Как сохранять данные в макрос при закрытии документа

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, макросы

В excel и word при первом запуске макроса необходимо сохранить определенные данные так, чтобы они сохранились после закрытия файла. Собственно как их сохранять?

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам нужно сохранить данные в конкретном документе, то поглядите на `variables`.

```
Sub docVariables()
    Dim aVar As Variable
    Dim isVarExist As Boolean
    Dim fName As String

    isVarExist = False
    fName = "Иванов Иван"
    ' Проверка на существование переменной
    For Each aVar In ActiveDocument.Variables
         If aVar.Name = "FullName" Then isVarExist = True: Exit For
    Next aVar
    ' Если переменная уже существует, то меняем её значение
    ' в противном случае создаём её
    If isVarExist Then
         ActiveDocument.Variables("FullName").Value = fName
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Variables.Add Name:="FullName", Value:=fName
    End If
    ' Обращение к переменной
    MsgBox ActiveDocument.Variables("FullName").Value
    ' Удаление переменной
    ActiveDocument.Variables("FullName").Delete
End Sub
```

Вот статья на эту тему: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306281.
Данный способ подходит только MS Word, в Excel, к сожалению, `variables` нет. Для него можно предложить хранение значений на скрытых листах.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: @metalurgus спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 0):

Можно также использовать CustomDocumentProperties

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Спасибо за уточнение

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?